How to route alerts based on the duration the alert condition has been true
I would like to set up notification for alerts from alertmanager such that I receive:

Slack notifications immediately
OpsGenie notifications if a given alert is firing for at least 1 hour
Email notifications if a given alert is firing at least for eight hours

I already have these notification integrations set up in my alertmanager config and they work except for the delay aspect.
I understand alertmanager itself doesn't have information about how long a given alert has been firing, and hence that information is not readily available for making the routing decision.
If there was some label in the alert generated by prometheus, I should be able to use that in alertmanager to make this decision fairly trivially. I don't want to create separate copy of the alerts in prometheus to just add an extra label.
I am guessing it should be possible to set labels on the alerts on the prometheus side based on how long the alert condition has been true. I couldn't find any pointers for this from reading the documentation and all the searching so far.

Could you do this using for?
rules.yaml:
groups:
  - name: some-alert-immediate
    rules:
      - alert: some-alert
        expr: same-promql
        labels:
          severity: slack
        annotations:
          summary: "Some Summary"
  - name: some-alert-an-hour
    rules:
      - alert: some-alert
        expr: same-promql
        for: 1h
        labels:
          severity: opsgenie
        annotations:
          summary: "Some Summary"
  - name: some-alert-an-hour
    rules:
      - alert: some-alert
        expr: same-promql
        for: 8h
        labels:
          severity: email
        annotations:
          summary: "Some Summary"

alertmanager.yaml:
global:

route:
  routes:
    - matchers:
      - severity="slack
      receiver: slack
    - matchers:
      - severity="opsgenie"
      receiver: opsgenie
    - matchers:
      - severity="email"
      receiver: email

receivers:
  - name: slack
  - name: opsgenie
  - name: email

See Routing tree editor and e.g. {severity="opsgenie"}

Yeah not creating a separate copy (or rather two extra copies) of each of my 200+ alerts is one of my constraints. If this can be set dynamically in prometheus based on how long this condition has been true, that would work. Any ideas if that is possible ?
